# Application launcher activity reopens when opening app from background

Tags: android

I have an app on the Google Play Store. I've found an interesting bug here - when I'm sending my app to background (by pressing home) and then clicking on the app icon again, it opens the main screen.

I read some article (https://medium.com/@elye.project/three-important-yet-unbeknown-android-app-launcher-behaviors-part-2-139a4d88157) about it, tried all application states, but the behavior remains the same. However, If I will open my ADB app (or from Studio) all works just fine.

How to solve this? My manifest file looks like following:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware..accelerometer"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="signin"
                android:scheme="appprefix" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.view.Acitivity2"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.view.Acitivity3"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

Comment: You mean if you are on `Acitivity2` and press home button, then when you come back into the app, `MainActivity` is resumed instead `Acitivity2`?

Comment: Yes. It happens when I'm pressing home button and then clicking on icon. And I found some bug - if after "restarting" I'm clicking onBack, then I can see my previous activitiy

Comment: Strange. And this only happens with Play Store version of app? Are you 100% sure that Play Store app code is exactly the same as yours when debugging?

Comment: Yep. It's the same code. And when I'm intalling apk on device throm fileexplore, I can repeat this bug, but throw adb - not

Comment: Try removing `singleTop` from application's tag. And if you don't need, remove it from all the activities too. Then try again, using file explorer.

Comment: It's not working... Launch mode removed in Play Market store version where I can find bug

Comment: As far as I know the `launchmode` attribute does not belong in the `application` tag. [Application Element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) :: It might cause an issue or just be ignored.

Comment: It's my code too. In standart state (in play market) there are no any launchModes

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround for market launches. The market launches the main activity on top of other activities. We never want this to happen. Instead, we should check if we are the root and if not, we finish the current. Add following code on your launcher activity onCreate()

```
 if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && 
              Intent.ACTION_MAIN.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            finish();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's works, but partly. I can see, how loading my mainactivity (onCreate call) and than launches other activity (old). It's a bit freeky for user. How can I avoid this visual affect?


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (!isTaskRoot) {

            if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && Intent.ACTION_MAIN == intent.action) {

                finish()
                return
            }
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main

Comment: If to be precise, Activity 2 is openning, but MainActivity opens to, but because we blocked it with you code, it's referting. But user can see it

Comment: I am using the same line of code but haven't seen any visual effects. Maybe my activity is very lightweight and it gets finished without any visual effects. The translucent background you may help

Comment: If Im running up from Stuido, I dont see any difference. But when I'm intalling it throw manual apk install, I can see it (I dont know why)

Comment: I have given you only workaround , This is the bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64108432 you can check